# How to run function when error raised in python

Tags: python

I have a function called `onError()`. When it is ran, it prints `"There was an error"`

I want this function to run whenever an error occurs, for example, if I raise `NameError`, the function runs.

Here is my code

```py
def onError():
    print("There was an error")

raise NameError
```

I know that try and except exist, but I want a way to do it without them.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a "global" exception handler by overriding `sys.excepthook`.

Here's an example.

```py
import sys

def onError(exception_type, value, traceback):
    print("There was an error")

sys.excepthook = onError
```